# Tornado's AsyncHTTPClient subclass

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, asynchronous, tornado

(python 3.6.4 and tornado 4.5.3)

When using :
 http_client = tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
the asynchronous http request fetching works fine.

But trying to define and use a subclass of AsyncHTTPClient got me into some kind of a deadlock when running the program (as opposed to the synchronous HTTPClient class where a subclass of it functioned well)

*Please correct me: If Tornado's AsynchHTTPClient class adheres to / inherits from the Configurable interface / abstract class , Then how it is possible to build objects from it? (Same rules as in Java?) . Is it that somehow something picks a default implementation for it among several built in ones?

"Configurable subclasses must define the class methods configurable_base and configurable_default, and use the instance method initialize instead of **init**. "  - Will The default ctor in the case of inheritance will call super.**init** ? Is this the reason for the problem?

From the Documentation it appears that inheriting from AsyncHTTPClient is not recommended / not a valid method to use it:

```
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", handle_response)
```

The constructor for this class is magic in several respects: It
actually creates an instance of an implementation-specific
subclass, and instances are reused as a kind of pseudo-singleton
(one per `.IOLoop`). The keyword argument `force_instance=True`
can be used to suppress this singleton behavior. Unless
`force_instance=True` is used, no arguments should be passed to
the `AsyncHTTPClient` constructor. The implementation subclass as
well as arguments to its constructor can be set with the static
method `configure()`
All `AsyncHTTPClient` implementations support a `defaults`
keyword argument, which can be used to set default values for
`HTTPRequest` attributes.  For example::

```
AsyncHTTPClient.configure(
    None, defaults=dict(user_agent="MyUserAgent"))
# or with force_instance:
client = AsyncHTTPClient(force_instance=True,
    defaults=dict(user_agent="MyUserAgent"))
```

additional questions:

1)Does buffering the response is a matter of choice?

3)When should I use the class tornado.web.RequestHandler ?

---

No errors at the moment but I'm not receiving a response after the actual fetch.

```
import sys
from tornado import ioloop, gen, httpclient
```

Under class SimpleAsyncHTTPClient(httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient):

```
#had to add this one (abstract function empty implementation? )
# I think that's the troublemaker
def fetch_impl(self, request, callback):
    pass

@gen.coroutine
def get(self, url):

    method = 'GET'
    print('send Async GET request ')
    res = yield self._fetch(url, method)
    print('after _fetch ...')
    return res

@gen.coroutine
def _fetch(self, url, method):
    print('send Asynchronous request ...')
    res = yield self.fetch(url, method=method)
    print('got a response')
    return res
```

Under a global:

@gen.coroutine

def ioloop_task():

```
yield gen.sleep(3)
url = 'http://google.com'
http_client = SimpleAsyncHTTPClient()

res = yield http_client.get(url)
res_code =  res.code
res_body =  res.body
print('return code: {}, body: {}....'.format(res_code, res_body[:60]))

print('do other stuff ....')
yield gen.sleep(2)

print(' task completed')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you've updated your question with additional details, and it has become very different from the original, I'd add another answer.

**The magic behind AsyncHTTPClient**

Consider this code:

```
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
print(http_client.__class__)

# Output:
<class 'tornado.simple_httpclient.SimpleAsyncHTTPClient'>
```

As you can see, `http_client` is an instance of `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient`, not `AsyncHTTPClient`. So, what's going on here?

If you look at the source code of [`AsyncHTTPClient`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpclient.py#L109), you'll see that it is inheriting the `tornado.utils.Configurable` class.

The most important piece of code in `Configurable` class is the `__new__` method which is responsible for all the magic. If you look at its [source code](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/util.py#L295-L313), you'll find that it will create an instance of whatever class is returned by the classmethod `configurable_default`.

Now, look at the source code of [`AsyncHTTPClient.configurable_default`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpclient.py#L151-L154). It is returning the `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient` class, and that is why the object we created above (`http_client`), is the instance of `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient`, not of `AsyncHTTPClient`.

Finally, yes, you're right that you need to create the `fetch_impl` method in your subclass. Because `AsyncHTTPClient` will call the `self.fetch_impl` method. You can see this in [this line in source code](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/httpclient.py#L263).

Though, `fetch_impl` hasn't been implemented in `AsyncHTTPClient` class, but it has been implemented in `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient`. You can find it [here](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/simple_httpclient.py#L111-L126).

---

**How to successfully subclass `AsyncHTTPClient`?**

I'd start by a looking at the [source code of `SimpleAsyncHTTPClient`](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/master/tornado/simple_httpclient.py#L39) and modify it to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

But why? You can just use `AsyncHTTPClient`.

If you're doing this for learning, here's a general outline of the concepts:

1. `yield` and `await` are for *pausing* a coroutine. But they're not the same. However, in Tornado, when the `yield` keyword is in a `gen.coroutine` decorated function, they both do the same things - that is suspending a coroutine until a future (or an [awaitable](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-awaitable)) is complete.
2. `return` is used for returning something from a function, I'm sure you already knew that.

---

When to use `yield` and when to use `await`?

If you're using Python older than 3.5, use `@gen.coroutine ... yield` syntax. For 3.5+, you should use the `async def ... await` syntax. Also, Tornado will [drop support for older Python](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-tornado/pErgXjAR77s/IsPH5FuVBQAJ) versions soon, so it's better to adhere to the new syntax.

Which brings me to point out that mixing these two doesn't seem a good idea. Get rid of the old syntax by replacing `@gen.coroutine` with `async` and `yield` with `await`.

---

A few comments about your code:

Let's take a look at the `_fetch` and `get` methods. Neither of them is returning anything.

To elaborate, in `get` method at `res = await self._fetch(url, method)`, the `res` will be `None` because `_fetch` isn't returning anything.
And the same this is happening in `ioloop_task` at `res =  http_client.get(url)`. `res` will be `None` because `get` isn't returning anything.

To fix this, simply return the `res` object from both `_fetch` and `get` methods.

Also, you don't really need the `_fetch` method. You can do those things in the `get` method:

```
async def get(url):
    ...
    res = await self.fetch(url, method=method)
    return res
```

In fact, you don't even need the `async ... await` syntax either. This will work just as fine:

```
def get(url):
    ...
    return self.fetch(url, method=method)
```

Why the second code example will work fine, I leave it as an exercise for you to figure out.

Comment: I'm not sure that the 2nd example (not using async +await or gen.coroutine + yield) is suppose to work as far as i tested it (even to the fetch function supports asynchronous execution)

Comment: @generationX The 2nd example will work as expected. The reason is that `self.fetch` will return a Future object, which you can `yield` in another coroutine. If you find this example confusing, feel free to ignore it. It's not very important, really.